# Android PreferenceScreen padding margin

Tags: android

I want to remove the padding/margins of a PreferenceScreen. See XML below.

I have tried everything on the

I removed the android:title to see if it would make it smaller but it seems like it is a set height like a CheckBoxPreference.  Any help would be great!

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/schedule_preferences">

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="screen_preference"
        android:title="@string/month1_title_screen"
        android:summary="@string/month1_summary_screen">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/Day1_title"
            android:summary="@string/Day1_summary"
            android:key="pref_Day1" />

        <!-- THIS ONE -->

        <PreferenceScreen
            android:dependency="pref_Day1"
            android:key="day1_screen"
            android:summary="@string/Extra_Options">

         <!-- THIS ONE -->

            <EditTextPreference
              android:title="@string/Day1_title"
              android:summary="@string/WO_Date"
              android:inputType="number"
              android:key="Day1_date" />
            <EditTextPreference
              android:title="@string/CT_title"
              android:key="Day1_comment" />

     </PreferenceScreen>

 </PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: I've tried 
            <PreferenceScreen
                android:dependency="pref_Day1"
                android:key="day1_screen"
                android:summary="@string/Extra_Options"
                android:paddingTop="-4sp"
                android:paddingBottom="-4sp">